# Can I access "Reason Phrase" from the HTTP Status-Line in NSHTTPURLResponse

Tags: iphone, ios, http, nsurlconnection

RFC 2616 specifying HTTP says - in section 6.1.1 - that part of the Status-Line is a 3-digit numeric Status Code AND a textual "Reason Phrase".

I am building an iPhone app, that is using NSURLConnection to access data over HTTP. I can get the HTTP Status Code without problems, but how can I access the "Reason Phrase"?

Here's my connection:didReceiveResponse: method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    httpStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    // Reason Phrase ??
}
```

To be specific, I do NOT mean the "explanation of what a code xxx means" text. I can lookup that in the RFC and those are static. I mean the text the server produced in the status line. An example of such a status line would be:

```
HTTP/1.1 412 ClientAppVersion: 0.10 < 0.11
```

and the Reason Phrase would be "ClientAppVersion: 0.10 < 0.11" here.

This example also gives a hint at what I am trying to do. I am building a REST-like API, and as such, I should use the HTTP status codes to indicate errors. But HTTP status codes were invented for HTTP and not for my app, so I try to cram extra information into the Reason Phrase.

Comment: The phrase will not be transmitted but you can lookup common ones yourself. It would be a massive overhead to transmit all that text. http://www.seoconsultants.com/w3c/status-codes/reason-phrases

Comment: @Lee Armstrong: the phrase IS transmitted, but it's an indication only, so servers shouldn't say anything useful in them. The status code should be used instead.

Comment: @lee-armstrong and @bruno : I have edited my question to make it more specific.

Comment: @polesen. As RFC 2616 says, "The Status-Code is intended for use by automata and the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user." Whatever server you're using is doing something it shouldn't do (an HTTP client shouldn't be expected to read or interpret the reason phrase). If there's an error message to give for such an error, it should be in the response entity, not in the reason-phrase.

Comment: @bruno : Yes, I know. I am bending HTTP to make it fit the REST idea. Back to the question though: Is there an API call to get access to the Reason Phrase?

Comment: furthermore, you seem to be abusing status 412 for something it's not defined for.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? I have the same problem

Comment: I didn't. I also ended up considering it to be a "bad idea". Put the reasoning of the API into content. HTTP status line wasn't meant for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on previous comments (this is not quite the answer you're looking for).

The HTTP specification (RFC 2616) states, [about status codes and reason-phrase](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1):

> The Status-Code is intended for use by
>   automata and the Reason-Phrase is
>   intended for the human user. The
>   client is not required to examine or
>   display the Reason- Phrase.

It's quite clear, from the text, that an HTTP client shouldn't be expected to read the reason-phrase. In fact, it's often a localized version that may be presented, if at all (not necessarily the one sent by the server).

The purpose of having standards and specifications such as HTTP is to be able to expect different compliant implementations (such as your server and the iOS libraries) to be able to interoperate. You should expect problems if you bend the specifications. In particular, don't be surprised if the library you want to use doesn't give you access to the reason-phrase.

I'm not quite sure how to interpret your comment ("I am bending HTTP to make it fit the REST idea.") I can assure you that REST can be implemented using HTTP without this sort of bending. I'm not sure where you got this idea of bending HTTP to fit the REST idea...

If you want to implement something to give an error reason the REST way, the cause should be given in the response message-body (or even maybe in a custom header), not in the reason-phrase. Even if it's a plain-text response, it's better than the reason phrase. For example:

Instead of:

```
HTTP/1.1 412 ClientAppVersion: 0.10 < 0.11
```

use:

```
HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
Content-Type: text/plain

ClientAppVersion: 0.10 < 0.11
```

or perhaps:

```
HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed
Content-Type: text/plain
X-My-Error: ClientAppVersion: 0.10 < 0.11
```

Note that you should return a message-body anyway (unless 204). [Status code 412](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.13) is also quite specifically related to preconditions based on headers (which you may be using):

> The precondition given in one or more
>   of the request-header fields evaluated
>   to false when it was tested on the
>   server. This response code allows the
>   client to place preconditions on the
>   current resource metainformation
>   (header field data) and thus prevent
>   the requested method from being
>   applied to a resource other than the
>   one intended.

Comment: Those are really good suggestions on alternatives, and they might be better than using the Reason Phrase. BUT: I would still like an answer to my original question: "CAN it be done? CAN I access the Reason Phrase through the iOS libraries?" :-)

Comment: Rather guess iOS SDK doesn't have HTTP fully implemented -
on Android SDK accessing the status text this is no problem at all. Even if the specs say: "The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-Phrase" doesn't mean that it should be unable to.

Comment: iOS developers are always so headstrong.  Just because Apple didn't provide it doesn't mean it shouldn't be provided.  Just because it isn't required doesn't mean it shouldn't provide access to an optional part of a W3 spec.

Comment: @Kevin Just so that we're clear, I'm not an iOS developer, and I have no particular opinion regarding whether or not Apple should provide this facility. I'm just saying it's a bad idea to try to rely on it, since the specification explicitly states that the client doesn't have to look at it. In addition, there are clean ways of giving an error message as HTTP stands. Why try to use one that is clearly going for a corner case of the HTTP specification?

Comment: @Bruno Your point about reliance is well taken and true.  Although I'd argue the client in this case should be the consumer of the HTTP library provided by Apple, not the HTTP library itself.  It seems arbitrary that Apple denies access to this optional data.

Comment: This answer is nonsensical.  The spec says that you shouldn't try to *parse* it, but obviously you need to be able to *retrieve* it if you're going to display it to the human user.

Comment: @GlennMaynard This is certainly ambiguous at best, since the "*client is not required to examine or display [it]*". It'd take that as the human user being the person debugging the network traffic, just like many protocols use English words (like "HELO", "GET", "MAIL", "QUIT" ...), when clearly none of these messages are intended to be shown to the end user. My main point was that, because it's problematic and almost certainly not intended for the end user as such, it shouldn't be used for the purpose of the question (note that it clearly isn't about being used by a human either).

Comment: Nope, it's completely clear.  It says the client is not *required* to display it.  It doesn't say that the client isn't allowed to, and there's nothing to suggest that a client shouldn't even have access to it.  The status message string is a basic part of the result that every full-featured HTTP library needs to expose.

Comment: @GlennMaynard Yes, but if you read *this* question, it clearly aims to use the reason phrase by automata, not by a human user. Hence, whilst the HTTP client may indeed be able to read it, it shouldn't be expected to, certainly not with the purpose of having some sort of network/REST API depend on it. Put it simply, an **automated** client that would need to interpret something like "`ClientAppVersion: 0.10 < 0.11`" meaningfully would be required to read that reason phrase. However "*The client is not required to examine or display the Reason- Phrase.*" (for humans) according to the spec.

Comment: That's not relevant.  This answer stated "It's quite clear, from the text, that an HTTP client shouldn't be expected to read the reason-phrase.", which is wrong.

Comment: @GlennMaynard "client" as in "automated client", as implied by the question. Anyway, that's the only thing it can be, since there's no mechanism in browsers to display this unless you're using developer tools. Status codes are never displayed to the user (even 404 messages sometimes displayed by the browser really come from resource representations, often default HTML pages for that status code).

Answer (score 0):

The class method localizedStringForStatusCode: on NSHTTPURLResponse will get you a localized phrase for the status code received in the response.

Comment: tiarks : Yes, but that is not it. That is just the static description of what a code xxx is. I have edited my question to be more specific.