# Read status line (status code and reason phrase) using AFNetworking's AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, afnetworking, asihttprequest, http-1.1, rfc2616

I am switching from `ASIHTTPRequest` to `AFNetworking` in an iOS application.

[RF2616 (HTTP/1.1)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1) defines a "status-line" by the combination of "Status Code" and "Reason Phrase". Sometimes the server adds some specific information in this "Reason Phrase" and I found it rather handy that ASIHTTPRequest allowed me to access it easily via

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = ...;
NSString *reason = request.responseStatusMessage;
```

My problem is that I can't find any way to do it with `AFHTTPRequestOperation`

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = ...;
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
```

In both completion/failure block of the operation i can get the status code by doing:

```
int statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];
```

But I can't find where to get the "Reason Phrase".

Some answers on StackOverflow suggest that it would be located in one of the entries of `[operation.response allHeaderFields]` but it's not.

An answer to this question << [Can I access "Reason Phrase" from the HTTP Status-Line in NSHTTPURLResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372047/can-i-access-reason-phrase-from-the-http-status-line-in-nshttpurlresponse) >>
suggests changing how the server behaves but that's not always an available option.

Any idea?

Comment: What URL are you working with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSHTTPURLResponse` does not implement a method that exposes the data, and the HTTP RFC does not a require it to.  AFNetworking uses `NSURLRequest` / `NSURLResponse`, and so AFNetworking cannot give it to you either.  ASIHTTPRequest can, on the other hand, because it uses the lower-level `CFNetwork` framework.

The advice given in the other answers, to move this information to your headers or body, is the best answer.

You can also [file an enhancement request with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com/), and / or stick with ASIHTTPRequest.

Comment: Ok. That was the answer I was afraid to hear :)